# Get value from bootstrap-timepicker24

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am experiencing difficulties with getting a text value from bootstrap-timepicker24 form.

jsp code:

```
<form action="#" class="form-horizontal form-bordered" id="shop-time">
  <div class="form-body form" >
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-md-4">Monday</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="input-group shop-monday-open-time">
            <input type="text" class="form-control timepicker timepicker-24">
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn default" type="button">
                  <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
                </button>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

js code:

```
// forms
var shopForm = $('#shop-time');
var shopMondayOpen = shopSave.find('.shop-monday-open-time');

// time picker listener
shopMondayOpen.on('changeTime.timepicker', function(open) {
  var time = dateInUTC(open.time);
});
```

But the event `changeTime` does not affect the listener. But if I just reload the page and stop at the breakpoint on this line:  `var shopMondayOpen = shopSave.find('.shop-monday-open-time')` line and evaluate `shopMondayOpen.val` at the console I get something like:

```
shopMondayOpen.val
jquery.min.js:4 function (a){var b,c,d,e=this[0];{if(arguments.length)return          d=m.isFunction(a),this.each(function(c){var e;1===this.nodeType&&(e=d?a.call(this,c,m(this).val()):a,null==e?e="":"number"==typeof e?e+="":m.isArray(e)&&(e=m.map(e,function(a){return null==a?"":a+""})),b=m.valHooks[this.type]||m.valHooks[this.nodeName.toLowerCase()],b&&"set"in b&&void 0!==b.set(this,e,"value")||(this.value=e))});if(e)return b=m.valHooks[e.type]||m.valHooks[e.nodeName.toLowerCase()],b&&"get"in b&&void 0!==(c=b.get(e,"value"))?c:(c=e.value,"string"==typeof c?c.replace(lc,""):null==c?"":c)}}
```

I tried to use timepicker-24 [manual](http://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/) but it didn't get me far..

Guess that I am missing something but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: I just have realized that I can use a value straithg from the controler, something like that: 

`<input type="text" class="form-control timepicker timepicker-24 shop-monday-open">
`

`var time = $('shop-monday-open').val`

..and it worked for me. Hope it can help somebody else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several days I have made a conclusion that only way you can get a value from a timepicker-24 is a value from conroler, as I have already said at tht comment to my post:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control timepicker timepicker-24 shop-monday-open"> 
var time = $('shop-monday-open').val
```